# PowerShell to Import VM without XML File

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a bunch of Hyper-V virtual disks I would like to import. 
My OS is Windows 8.

There are official Microsoft labs images and I can import them from the GUI by following this procedures:

1. Select Import Virtual Machine
2. Select the folder containing the virtual image
3. Select the Virtual Machine
4. Select "Register the virtual machine in-place" for the Import Type

This works perfectly, but since I have a lot of labs, I want to automate this is via a  PowerShell script. The Import-VM command accepts a Path parameter which is the path to the VM's XML file. However, the XML files do not exist in my machines until the import is completed via the GUI.

I need some guidance on how I can automate the manual procedure above via PowerShell, i.e. leverage Import-VM to import from a folder path only.

This would save me a ton of time when re-creating my labs across my student's machines.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
The trick was to call Import-VM and specify a path to the .exp which comes with the labs.

```
Import-VM -Path $expfile
```

This post really helped: http://vniklas.djungeln.se/2012/04/04/importing-vm%C2%B4s-with-powershell-into-win8-hyper-v-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

Use `New-VM` cmdlet instead ie.  `New-VM –Name "VM1" –MemoryStartupBytes 1GB –VHDPath C:\vhds\yourImage.vhdx -Path C:\VMS`

Run `get-help New-VM -Examples` or visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848537.aspx for more info.

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for. I do not want to specify the VM name, memory etc. when importing the VM.

I am able to do this by selecting an existing VM folder from the GUI "Import VM" command but do not understand why it is not possible to do the same using Import-VM PowerShell ?